# ExecuteNonQuery() versus ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, executenonquery

I'm doing some more working with AJAX, and JSON calls, and I've noticed the the SqlCommand Object has a two methods, ExecuteNonQuery(), and ExecuteNonQueryAsync(), what exactly are the differences in these methods?

Comment: First one is blocking call, 2nd one is asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

If you call `ExecuteNonQuery` your code will wait until it completes.
If you call `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` your code will continue execution and you can track when the actual call to `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` completes via `Task<int>` object that it returns.